# io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock In Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk, android-unit-testing

Mockk Error in android Koltin Unit test. matching with Two URL

io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock

```
@Before
    fun setUp() {
        mockkStatic(Uri::class)
        every { Uri.parse(any()) } returns mockk()
        every { Uri.Builder() } returns mockk()// Error occurred here
   
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true)
    }
```

```
 @Test
    fun isParamTest() {
        every { Uri.parse(any()) } returns mockk(relaxed = true)
        every { Uri.Builder() } returns mockk(relaxed = true)
        val  inputURL  ="https://test"
        val expected="https://test"
       parameterKey="test",value="testvalue"
        val Output = getWebURL(inputURL,parameterKey,value)
        assertThat(Output).isEqualTo(expected)
    }
```

```
    private Uri buildURI(String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    
        // build url with parameters.
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    
        return builder.build();
    }

Thanks in Advance

Need to solve this unit test case
```

Comment: Try adding `mockkStatic(Uri.Builder::class)`. Maybe mockkStatic does not apply to nested classes.

Comment: @levi Still same error

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.Builder()` is not a static function call of `Uri` but a constructor call of `Uri.Builder`. Thus, you cannot use `every` here. Instead, you can use a [constructor mock](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks):

```
mockkConstructor(Uri.Builder::class)
```

Then every call to `Uri.Builder()` automatically returns a mock.

Comment: Hi, In which function i need to add this @Before /@Test ?

Comment: It depends on your test setup. I guess you can just replace the `every { Uri.Builder() } ...` line with the `mockkConstructor...` line.